# Convert a number to a string literal with constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for a way to convert a number to a string literal at compile time. It should look something like this:

```
template <unsigned num>
struct num_to_string {
    constexpr static char value[] = /* ... magic goes here ... */;
};
```

So that `num_to_string<5>::value` is equal to `"5"` or `{'5', '\0'}`.

This can be useful for generating a string at compile time from a number that is the result of some other constexpr number calculations.

Also note that I'm only interested in `unsigned` numbers since that should be easier to deal with. Bonus points for the signed version :)

EDIT:
Note that this is similar to [C++ convert integer to string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713420/c-convert-integer-to-string-at-compile-time), but not the same. Here I explicitly want something that uses constexpr and not macros to aid in generic programming.

Comment: I should think three years is long enough to discover how to format code blocks!!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this "code plz" question is strictly on-topic, but I think it's interesting enough to keep. May give it a go later.

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713420/c-convert-integer-to-string-at-compile-time

Comment: @vsoftco: .... aww :(

Comment: give it a try without boost ...

Comment: Give it a try without any arms whilst you're at it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, too messy using boost?

Comment: The dup is not exactly the same. I'm not interested in a solution with macros or boost::mpl. I'm looking specifically for something with constexpr and C++11/14.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23444818/420683

Comment: Is C++11/14 the same as C++0.786, or C++0? Hmm, you decide....

Comment: Actually, this is quite simple for literals: `template<char... cs> auto operator"" _cs() -> std::array<char, sizeof...(cs)+1> { return {cs..., '\0'}; }` [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/249d38e58b32e481)

Comment: @dyp, it's even easier than that: `auto operator""_cs(const char* lit) { return lit; }` - [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a8022c6e40669d4)

Comment: @tclamb Oh! I didn't know enough about raw literal operators, it seems.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Variadic templates to the rescue. :)

```
namespace detail
{
    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct to_chars { static const char value[]; };

    template<unsigned... digits>
    constexpr char to_chars<digits...>::value[] = {('0' + digits)..., 0};

    template<unsigned rem, unsigned... digits>
    struct explode : explode<rem / 10, rem % 10, digits...> {};

    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct explode<0, digits...> : to_chars<digits...> {};
}

template<unsigned num>
struct num_to_string : detail::explode<num> {};
```

As always, here's a [live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0eb4157accbba035) showing usage and the (relevant) generated assembly.

---

It's straightforward to adapt this approach to support negative numbers as well. Here's a more generic form that requires the user to input the integer's type:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<uint8_t... digits> struct positive_to_chars { static const char value[]; };
    template<uint8_t... digits> constexpr char positive_to_chars<digits...>::value[] = {('0' + digits)..., 0};

    template<uint8_t... digits> struct negative_to_chars { static const char value[]; };
    template<uint8_t... digits> constexpr char negative_to_chars<digits...>::value[] = {'-', ('0' + digits)..., 0};

    template<bool neg, uint8_t... digits>
    struct to_chars : positive_to_chars<digits...> {};

    template<uint8_t... digits>
    struct to_chars<true, digits...> : negative_to_chars<digits...> {};

    template<bool neg, uintmax_t rem, uint8_t... digits>
    struct explode : explode<neg, rem / 10, rem % 10, digits...> {};

    template<bool neg, uint8_t... digits>
    struct explode<neg, 0, digits...> : to_chars<neg, digits...> {};

    template<typename T>
    constexpr uintmax_t cabs(T num) { return (num < 0) ? -num : num; }
}

template<typename Integer, Integer num>
struct string_from : detail::explode<(num < 0), detail::cabs(num)> {};
```

Its usage is like:

```
string_from<signed, -1>::value
```

as demonstrated in the [live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/322ba120a8642756).

Comment: I really like this solution, there is only one point I'd like to mention: It is not really `constexpr`. I realized that when I wanted to use it and tested it with `static_assert()`. It's no big deal to make it `constexpr`, though: Define the `value` arrays as `constexpr` and initialize them in the declaration (necessary).

Comment: Why 1st `template<unsigned... digits>` and second `template<uint8_t... digits>` have different types, shouldn't they be same?

Comment: Very nice. `positive_to_chars` needs an additional specialization to handle the case when the number is exactly zero. Result should be "0", not empty string.

Comment: Is this still the preferred way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for this finding. The variadic template is beautiful. An exquisite application of recursion and declarative programming!