# Is it possible to generate a string at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, string-formatting, compile-time

In the following example I use `snprintf` inside a template function to create a string that contains the value of the template parameter `N`. I would like to know if there is a way to generate this string at compile time instead.

```c++
template <unsigned N>
void test()
{
    char str[8];
    snprintf(str, 8, "{%d}", N);
}
```

Comment: Why cant it happen at run time? Also, you might want to look at how C++ templating works (its all compile time based).

Comment: Exact duplicate of [C++ convert integer to string at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713420/c-convert-integer-to-string-at-compile-time)

Comment: Whatever it's worth at this point, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5c4c0c3b63b0c1b

Comment: @Dgrin91 It totally could happen at run-time, but it would be cool if it didn't have to.

Comment: @metacubed It's not really an exact duplicate. I'm looking a string that contains more than just the number. Look at the code and see the format string. `"{%d}"` not `"%d"`.

Comment: @Chris_F the linked question describes a macro - you can put any extra characters in there as per your needs. Even the scenario of the question (a template parameter) is the same. I could change my comment to "almost duplicate" if you like... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit more digging around I came across this on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24000041/897778

Adapted for my use case I get:

```c++
namespace detail
{
    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct to_chars { static const char value[]; };

    template<unsigned... digits>
    const char to_chars<digits...>::value[] = {'{', ('0' + digits)..., '}' , 0};

    template<unsigned rem, unsigned... digits>
    struct explode : explode<rem / 10, rem % 10, digits...> {};

    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct explode<0, digits...> : to_chars<digits...> {};
}

template<unsigned num>
struct num_to_string : detail::explode<num / 10, num % 10>
{};

template <unsigned N>
void test()
{
    const char* str = num_to_string<N>::value;
}
```

`boost::mpl` was also suggested, but this code seems simpler.