# Appending a string literal with a compile time generated integer

Tags: string, c++11, gcc

I'm trying to generate a string during compile-time that contains a constant string and a couple calculated integers.

This string is to be used in GCC's `__attribute__((section("")))` directive.

The purpose of the whole thing is to put a few variables in an ELF file, each with a unique section name.

I used to do this by compiling each object file with `-DSOME_SYMBOL=<file_source_CRC>` to differentiate between object files, and `__COUNTER__` to differentiate between variables inside of a single object file. (We use this because of a requirement from our logging solution)

So the resulting code would be used using something like this:

```
#define SOME_MACRO(msg) {\
    static const char *messageBuffer __section__((section(".msg" ## #SOME_SYMBOL ## #__COUNTER__))) = {msg};\
} // Approximation

SOME_MACRO("This is a string");
```

This solution works great, but it requires support from the build-system (calculating the CRC and injecting it as a GCC `-D` flag), and it became a bit of an overhead when we moved from Makefile to SCons.

So I searched for another solution, and found this [compile time CRC solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627020/constexpr-CRC-using-user-defined-literal), but I got a bit lost when trying to figure out how to append it to the string.

After a bit more searching, I found the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999573/convert-a-number-to-a-string-literal-with-constexpr), which explains how to convert an integer to a string using template metaprogramming, but I still couldn't figure out how to append the strings (again, during compile time).

I'd love to find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible - according to code in [c-attribs.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/85e8db4295ea3fb575be2c7c68c28dedf663fb07/gcc/c-family/c-attribs.c#L1865) GCC requires `section`s operand to be a string literal:

```
if (TREE_CODE (TREE_VALUE (args)) != STRING_CST)
  {
    error ("section attribute argument not a string constant");
    goto fail;
  }
```

Section attribute is normally used on embedded systems where build systems already do a lot of additional work (generation of linker scripts, overlays, etc.) so there's little incentive to make it more intelligent. Relying on build system is your best bet.