# How to Interpret the Inheritance in Variadic Template?

Tags: c++, c++11

I came across this post:
[Convert a number to a string literal with constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999573/convert-a-number-to-a-string-literal-with-constexpr)

And the answer is quite interesting:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct to_chars { static const char value[]; };

    template<unsigned... digits>
    const char to_chars<digits...>::value[] = {('0' + digits)..., 0};

    template<unsigned rem, unsigned... digits>
    struct explode : explode<rem / 10, rem % 10, digits...> {};

    template<unsigned... digits>
    struct explode<0, digits...> : to_chars<digits...> {};
}

template<unsigned num>
struct num_to_string : detail::explode<num> {};
```

My questions are:

1. "struct explode : explode" declares explode inherits from explode; how about "struct explode<0, digits...> : to_chars"?
2. What's the function for the '0' as the first template parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a recursive formula with a partial specialization that serves as a termination condition.

```
explode<1234>
```

inherits from:

```
explode<123, 4>          // 1234 / 10 = 123, 1234 % 10 = 4
```

inherits from:

```
explode<12, 3, 4>        // 123 / 10 = 12, 123 % 10 = 3
```

inherits from:

```
explode<1, 2, 3, 4>      // 12 / 10 = 1, 12 % 10 = 2
```

inherits from:

```
explode<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>   // 1 / 10 = 0, 1 % 10 = 1
```

At this point, the left-most value (referred to as `rem` in the primary template) is `0`, so it matches the partial specialization:

```
template <unsigned... digits>
struct explode<0, digits...> : to_chars<digits...> {};
```

(indicating that the whole number was turned into separate digits) which eventually inherits from:

```
to_chars<1, 2, 3, 4>
```

Finally, `to_chars` expands the parameter pack into a `char` array, also turning the digits into characters, so that `1` becomes `'1'`, `2` becomes `'2'`, and so on:

```
const char to_chars<1, 2, 3, 4>::value[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', 0 };
```

Here, `0` is the null terminating character, so that `value` can be treated as if it were a string.

Comment: Very interesting that it "keeps" inheriting from explode through variadiac template expansion and then inherits from a different struct at the end (base case).  Thanks!