# Expand std::tuple to use as initialiser for class

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I want to use all elements of a `std::tuple` as an initialiser for a class. Is there a simpler way than doing `std::get<i-th element>(std::tuple)` for each element of the tuple?

Minimum working example with `std::get`:

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>

struct A
{
    std::string string1;
    int intVal;
    std::string string2;
};

int main()
{
  std::tuple< std::string, int, std::string > myTuple("S1", 42, "S2");

  A myA{ std::get<0>(myTuple), std::get<1>(myTuple), std::get<2>(myTuple) };

  assert( myA.string1 == "S1" );
  assert( myA.intVal  == 42   );
  assert( myA.string2 == "S2" );
}
```

See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a5d45dbf1461407 for Live example

Comment: E.g. see [P0209](http://wg21.link/p0209).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) commented there's already a proposal for this [P0209R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0209r0.pdf). Consequently, until it's in the standard you could do something along these lines:

```
template<typename C, typename T, std::size_t... I>
decltype(auto) make_from_tuple_impl(T &&t, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return C{std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(t))...};
}

template<typename C, typename... Args, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>>
decltype(auto) make_from_tuple(std::tuple<Args...> const &t) {
  return make_from_tuple_impl<C>(t, Indices());
}
```

And initialize your class as:

```
A myA{make_from_tuple<A>(myTuple)};
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d92c8b18a2ce147d)

You could also hand-craft `index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence` for this to work in C++11 as proposed by [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27125297/2352671), and change to:

```
namespace idx {
  template <std::size_t...> struct index_sequence {};

  template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
  struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> {};

  template <std::size_t... Is>
  struct make_index_sequence<0u, Is...> : index_sequence<Is...> { using type = index_sequence<Is...>; };
}

template<typename C, typename T, std::size_t... I>
C make_from_tuple_impl(T &&t, idx::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return C{std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(t))...};
}

template<typename C, typename... Args, typename Indices = idx::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>>
C make_from_tuple(std::tuple<Args...> const &t) {
  return make_from_tuple_impl<C>(t, Indices());
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b380b3c1c51aa0b5)

Comment: Solution is fine. Unfortunately, this solution requires C++14 which is currently not available for me. I backported backport index_sequence and make_index_sequence so I can still use it. Fine

Comment: @meddle0106 I'll try to give a c++11 version as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything standard that might help you.

However you can do it in following way:

Do `c-tor` in `A`?

```
struct A
{
    std::string string1;
    int intVal;
    std::string string2;

    template<class T>
    A(const T &t) :
               string1(std::get<0>(t), 
               intVal(std::get<1>(t)), 
               string2(std::get<2>(t)){}
};
```

Alternatively you can do factory like function:

```
    template<class T>
    A createA(const T &t){
        return A { 
               std::get<0>(t), 
               std::get<1>(t), 
               std::get<2>(t)
        };
    }
```

Code is untested and might have syntax errors.

Comment: Because you have strings, you might do some more code to handle universal references and to `std::move` / `std::forward` the strings.