# Several questions about metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I hope to get a compile-time array, so come to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12108694/6949852). Below is codes from the answer:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template<int ...>
struct seq { };

template<int N, int ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };

template<int ...S>
struct gens<0, S...> {
  typedef seq<S...> type;
};

constexpr int f(int n) {
  return n;
}

template <int N>
class array_thinger {
  typedef typename gens<N>::type list;

  template <int ...S>
  static constexpr std::array<int,N> make_arr(seq<S...>) {
    return std::array<int,N>{{f(S)...}};
  }
public:
  static constexpr std::array<int,N> arr = make_arr(list()); 
};

template <int N>
constexpr std::array<int,N> array_thinger<N>::arr;

int main() {
  std::copy(begin(array_thinger<10>::arr), end(array_thinger<10>::arr), 
            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

But I am a newbie for metaprogramming, so here are two questions:

1. what is the syntax of `struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...>`? It seems like `Delegating constructors` in c++0x, but I'm not sure.
2. what is the usage of `struct seq` and `typedef seq<S...> type`? Ahh, I also have no good command of template.

Comment: **1.** It's inheritance. `gens<N, S...>` is derived from `gens<N-1, N-1, S...>` **2.** It's a plain old `typedef`. The name `type` is declared as an alias for the type `seq<S...>`

Comment: The example you saw is a more complicated implementation of an integer sequence, which is recursion with divide and conquer. It is used to avoid large instantiation depths.

Comment: For a simpler example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27125297/4832499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a template which calls it self in recursive way.

If you write:

```
gens<3>::type
```

it uses your template

```
template<int N, int ...S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> { };
```

For that N becomes 3 and the parameters in S are none. The template struct itself derives from `gens<N-1, N-1, S...>` which then becomes here `gens<2,2>`. This will again call ( recursive! ) itself.

So the gens template is called with N=2 and S is a list with one element which contains one int : 2. That again calls `gens`, now with `gens<1,1,2>.

That repeat until N becomes 0. Now, because of the specialization of gens:

```
template<int ...S>
    struct gens<0, S...> {
    typedef seq<S...> type;
};
```

this specialization will be called. So here we get gens<0,0,1,2>. So N is 0 and S is a list of 0,1,2. Now the template generate the type `type`. Type is now seq< 0,1,2>.

As gens derives recursive from itself, you can get type from that sequence of inheritance, because the specialization for 0 is the root of the struct.

So you can write:

```
 gens<3>::type
```

which is: `seq<0,1,2>`