# How to initialise an array of N function pointers to function templates indexed from 0..N-1?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list, static-initialization

Given a function pointer array of `function_sig`, I want to initialise it to a set of template function pointers that are index via a template parameter.  Is this possible?

E.g.

```
template<int I>
void fn() { /* do something */ }

typedef void(*function_sig)();

template<int ARRAY_SIZE>
struct items
{
  static function_sig array[ARRAY_SIZE];
};

template<int ARRAY_SIZE>
function_sig items<ARRAY_SIZE>::array = { /* what do I put here? */ };
```

So, is there something that I can put in the initialiser list, such that `items<ARRAY_SIZE>::array` will be initialised to `{ fn<0>, fn<1>, ..., fn<ARRAY_SIZE-1> }`?

NOTE: I know of a way to do this with preprocessor magic, but I'd like to try without that.  Currently, I'm thinking I'll have to do away with the array and replace it with something that would act like an array, but that would lead to a search of O(N) when indexing the pseudo-array, which I'd like to not do.

Comment: Does either of these Q&A's help you: [c++11 constexpr flatten list of std::array into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068481/c11-constexpr-flatten-list-of-stdarray-into-array) or [Implementation C++14 make_integer_sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424477/implementation-c14-make-integer-sequence)?

Comment: @MicroVirus, possibly, though this is for a c++11 compiler (VS2013).  I'll still read through those and see if I can come up with something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is to get a variadic range from 0 to `ARRAY_SIZE - 1`.

I propose a solution that transfer `array` in a base class `itemsH`

```
#include <iostream>


template <std::size_t ...>
struct range
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct rangeH 
 { using type = typename rangeH<N-1U, N-1U, Next ... >::type; };

template <std::size_t ... Next >
struct rangeH<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = range<Next ... >; };


template<int I>
void fn() { std::cout << "[" << I << "]" << std::endl; }

typedef void(*function_sig)();

template <typename T>
struct itemsH;

template <std::size_t ... RNG>
struct itemsH<range<RNG...>>
 {
   static function_sig array[sizeof...(RNG)];
 };

template<std::size_t ARRAY_SIZE>
struct items : public itemsH<typename rangeH<ARRAY_SIZE>::type>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... RNG>
function_sig itemsH<range<RNG...>>::array[sizeof...(RNG)] = { fn<RNG>... };


int main ()
 {
   items<10>  i_10;

   for ( unsigned ui = 0U ; ui < 10 ; ++ui )
      i_10.array[ui]();

   return 0;
 }
```

p.s.: I've changed the type of `ARRAY_SIZE` from `int` to `size_t`; hoping isn't a problem

p.s.2: sorry for my bad English.

**--- edit: added C++14 example ---**

If you (when you) can use C++14, the you can use `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`, throwing away `range` and `rangeH`.

The example become

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


template<int I>
void fn() { std::cout << "[" << I << "]" << std::endl; }

typedef void(*function_sig)();

template <typename T>
struct itemsH;

template <std::size_t ... RNG>
struct itemsH<std::index_sequence<RNG...>>
 { static function_sig array[sizeof...(RNG)]; };

template<std::size_t ARRAY_SIZE>
struct items : public itemsH<std::make_index_sequence<ARRAY_SIZE>>
 { };

template <std::size_t ... RNG>
function_sig itemsH<std::index_sequence<RNG...>>::array[sizeof...(RNG)]
   = { fn<RNG>... };


int main ()
 {
   items<10>  i_10;

   for ( unsigned ui = 0U ; ui < 10 ; ++ui )
      i_10.array[ui]();

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Your English is fine and the switch to `std::size_t` is fine.  I only used `int` because I was lazy. :D  I would usually use `std::size_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <array>

template<int... Is>
struct int_seq { };

namespace detail {

template<int I, int... Is>
struct make_int_seq : make_int_seq<I - 1, I, Is...> { };

template<int... Is>
struct make_int_seq<0, Is...> {
    using type = int_seq<0, Is...>;
};

} // namespace detail

template<int SizeN>
using make_int_seq = typename detail::make_int_seq<SizeN - 1>::type;

template<int I>
void fn() { /* do something */ }

//typedef void(*function_sig)();
using function_sig = void(*)();

template<int ARRAY_SIZE>
struct items {
    static std::array<function_sig, ARRAY_SIZE> array;
};

template<int... Is>
std::array<function_sig, sizeof...(Is)> create_items_array(int_seq<Is...>) {
    return {{ &fn<Is>... }};
}

template<int ARRAY_SIZE>
std::array<function_sig, ARRAY_SIZE> items<ARRAY_SIZE>::array
  = create_items_array(make_int_seq<ARRAY_SIZE>{});
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58b3e38dedc8ff77)</kbd>

With C++14, `int_seq` et al disappear in favor of `std::integer_sequence` et al.

Comment: @Adrian : No, C-arrays are not copyable and thus cannot be returned from functions, and we need the `create_items_array` factory function.

Comment: FYI, some slight modification would have to be made with upgrading to c++14, as your `make_int_seq` will generate 0..N, where as `std::make_integer_sequence` generates 0..N-1.

Comment: @Adrian : [No, it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/728d7ff9f9771963), and I've no idea why you think it would...