# How do you implement compile-time string conversion functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Proposal [n4121](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4121.pdf) looks like it's going to add a `std::string_literal` type. It contains code like:

```
template<size_t n> struct string_literal { char data [n]; }
```

and:

```
template <size_t N> 
constexpr int stoi( const string_literal<N>& str, 
                    size_t* idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

And here's my Number class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Number
{
private:
    T t;
public:
    constexpr Number(const T& t)
        : t(t)
    {
    }

    constexpr Number(const std::string& s);

    constexpr operator T() const
    {
        return t;
    }
};

template <>
constexpr Number<int>::Number(const std::string& s)
    : t(std::stoi(s))
{
}
```

I've taken a look at [How do I convert a C string to a int at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195176/how-do-i-convert-a-c-string-to-a-int-at-compile-time) but it only works for C strings. and `c_str()` is non-constexpr. Also on top of that, this doesn't cover `stol`, `stoul`, `stoll`, `stof`, `stod`... and so on. Who knows if this proposal will make it into the standard. Also I don't want to wait 3 years for this library change to happen. How do I implement it in the moment, now?

---

Here's my attempt so far:

```
namespace lib
{
    constexpr bool is_digit(char c) {
        return c <= '9' && c >= '0';
    }

    constexpr int stoi_impl(const char* str, int value = 0) {
        return *str ?
                is_digit(*str) ?
                    stoi_impl(str + 1, (*str - '0') + value * 10)
                    : throw "compile-time-error: not a digit"
                : value;
    }

    constexpr int stoi(const char* str) {
        return stoi_impl(str);
    }

    template<size_t n> struct string_literal { char data [n]; };

    template < class charT, size_t N> 
    constexpr string_literal<N> 
        make_string_literal( const charT(&arr)[N])
        {
            string_literal<N> sl;
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                sl.data[i] = arr[i];
            return sl;
        }
}

template <typename T>
struct Number
{
private:
    T t;
public:
    constexpr Number(const T& t)
        : t(t)
    {
    }

    constexpr Number(const std::size_t N, const lib::string_literal<N>& s);

    constexpr operator T() const
    {
        return t;
    }
};

template <>
constexpr Number<int>::Number(const std::size_t N, const lib::string_literal<N>& s)
    : t(lib::stoi(s.data))
{
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto s = lib::make_string_literal("123456789");
    constexpr Number<int> n { sizeof(s.data), s };

    return 0;
}

main.cpp:44:69: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    constexpr Number(const std::size_t N, const lib::string_literal<N>& s);
                                                                    ^
main.cpp:53:78: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
constexpr Number<int>::Number(const std::size_t N, const lib::string_literal<N>& s)
                                                                             ^
main.cpp:29:38: error: cannot initialize an array element of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'const char [10]'
            return string_literal<N>{arr};
                                     ^~~
main.cpp:60:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'lib::make_string_literal<char, 10>' requested here
    auto s = lib::make_string_literal("123456789");
```

Comment: You cannot use `std::string`s directly. However, try the `str_const` solution mentioned and linked to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c).

Comment: So the problem is not choosing a function based on type, but converting from string to int at compile time. I think your title should reflect that.

Comment: How did you form your `std::string` at compile time if it wasn't using a string literal?

Comment: Why pass `N` when you can deduce it?  `template<size_t N> constexpr Number(const lib::string_literal<N>& s);`?

Comment: If you have C++14 support, why bother with that recursive `stoi_impl` and the ternary operators?

Comment: Here's something I've written a while ago in C++14 style constexpr: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23445223

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented sophisticated compile-time string to scalar converters. Take a look at [**`Constainer::strToFloat`**](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/Parser.hxx#L162) and [**`Constainer::strToInt`**](https://github.com/Arcoth/Constainer/blob/master/Parser.hxx#L67).

Examples from the testcase file:

```
static_assert( strToInt<int>(" 6849.") == 6849 );
static_assert( strToInt<signed char>(" -128aefws") == -128 );
static_assert( strToInt<unsigned>(" \t-0") == 0 );
static_assert( strToInt<unsigned>(" -0x0Xx", 0, 0) == 0 );
static_assert( strToInt<unsigned>(" +0xFF", 0, 0) == 0xFF );
static_assert( strToInt<unsigned>(" +077", 0, 0) == 7+8*7 );
static_assert( strToInt<unsigned>("11000", 0, 2) == 24 );

/**< These should go well on most implementations. */
static_assert( strToFloat<double>("+123.456789e0") == 123.456789 );
static_assert( strToFloat<double>("-0x1.Bc70a3D70A3d7p+6") == -111.11 );
static_assert( strToFloat<double     >("-1.18973e+4932") == -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() );
static_assert( strToFloat<long double>("-1.18973e+4932") != -std::numeric_limits<long double>::infinity() );
static_assert( strToFloat<double>("-0x.8p-1") == -0.25 );
```